# Compiling module crc32_intel_glue fails

Tags: linux, compiling, kernel-modules, gcc, intel

I have two CentOS hosts and want to install the kernel module crc32_intel_glue. 
I don't find it in the official repo, so I tried to build it from source, and failed.

I downloaded crc32c-intel_glue.c and Makefile from this web page:

> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/arch/x86/crypto/

I tried

```
yum install kernel-headers
make crc32c-intel_glue
```

but it outputs a ton of errors:

```
cc     crc32c-intel_glue.c   -o crc32c-intel_glue
crc32c-intel_glue.c:27:24: error: linux/init.h: No such file or directory
crc32c-intel_glue.c:28:26: error: linux/module.h: No such file or directory
crc32c-intel_glue.c:31:34: error: crypto/internal/hash.h: No such file or directory
crc32c-intel_glue.c:32:34: error: crypto/internal/simd.h: No such file or directory
crc32c-intel_glue.c:34:29: error: asm/cpufeatures.h: No such file or directory
crc32c-intel_glue.c:35:31: error: asm/cpu_device_id.h: No such file or directory
crc32c-intel_glue.c:36:22: error: asm/simd.h: No such file or directory
```

etc...

---

CentOS 6.10

```
zgrep CONFIG_CRYPTO_CRC32C_INTEL /boot/config-*
```

returns

```
CONFIG_CRYPTO_CRC32C_INTEL=m
```

I looked for `crc32c-intel.ko` and I found it:

```
/lib/modules/2.6.32-754.14.2.el6.x86_64/kernel/arch/x86/crypto/crc32c-intel.ko
```

I want to compile the module on Centos 5.11, to understand how it works.

Comment: Which CentOS version? Also, do you have the CentOS kernel config available? (Check /boot). If so, check it for `CONFIG_CRYPTO_CRC32C_INTEL`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that crc32c-intel.ko you found is the module you're looking for. Note how it matches the driver name and aliases in that source file. Is it not available on 5.11? You often can't grab modules from a newer kernel without upgrading the kernel entirely (or work backporting the module).